# Changing background colours of active x option buttons through variables turns them black

Tags: excel, vba

I have some odd (as in I don't understand it) behaviour in excel.
I have quite a few `optionbuttons` that I want to change the background colour of. In total there's something like 15 buttons and 3 (possibly 4) colours.
This works perfectly if I simply assign them the RGB code itself.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

OptionButton1.BackColor = RGB(0, 150, 79) 'Dark Green
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4

End Sub
```

however when I try to create variables containing the RGB codes like this:

```
 Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

    OptionButton1.BackColor = DGn 'Dark Green
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4

 End Sub
```

the buttons turn black like so:

[image]

Since there are quite a few buttons I'd love to just assign the colours once and then simply type DGn or Ylw instead of having to constantly CTRL-C, CTRL-V

Code is in `ThisWorkbook`

```
Dim DGn As Long
Dim LGn As Long
Dim Ylw As Long


Public Sub Workbook_Open()
DGn = RGB(0, 150, 79)
LGn = RGB(138, 201, 49)
Ylw = RGB(249, 234, 5)
End Sub
```

Any suggestions are appreciated! Have a nice nice day/evening.

Comment: so your code with your variables is `OptionButton1.BackColor = DGn` for example?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. I'll edit my question to be more concise

Comment: Try: `DGn = 5215744`

Comment: You will need to add those to the `Worksheet_Activate` event on the worksheet that the buttons are found on.

Comment: @Nick i've tried that code within a cell and both ways works, using the `RGB()`or the variable.

Comment: Do your variables ever change? ie Could you create them as constants? If you've stopped your code at any point in testing it's possibly removed the values assigned. Try entering ?DGn in the immediate window and see what value it returns

Comment: @ZackE Sadly doesn't seem to work either. I also tried @cybernetic.nomad 's approach using the windows colour equivalent `5215744`. And neither did that.

Comment: @Dave No I doubt they would change so using them as constants wouldn't be an issue. Just gave it a try though and apparently VBA doesn't allow RGB as constants.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is using `vbGreen` instead of `RGB`  Also you have the Sub set as `Private`, which will only apply to code in the `Workbook_Open` event and not in any other modules.

Comment: @ZackE Thanks a lot for taking the time to make all these suggestions, sadly nothing has worked so far. I'll play around with it some more in the morning and hopefully I'll find a solution. Regarding your comments i sadly can't use `vbGreen` because the colours are pre-set and I'm not allowed to change them. Also yes I had already changed `private sub` to `public sub` because I noticed that mistake too. Will edit the question to reflect.

Comment: Try to put your variables as 'Public' in different module than ThisWorkbook

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of every code module?  If you don't then add it and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of a regular module:

```
Public Const DGn As Long = 5215744   'RGB(0, 150, 79)
Public Const LGn As Long = 3262858   'RGB(138, 201, 49)
Public Const Ylw As Long = 387833    'RGB(249, 234, 5)
```

You can't directly use `RGB()` in a constant because a constant's value needs to be known at *compile time* and `RBG()` doesn't execute until *runtime*.

To convert the values, go to the Immediate pane in the VB editor and type (eg) `? RGB(138, 201, 49)` and hit enter - you will get the Long result which you can then use in your constant.

Comment: Great answer Tim - I experimented with trying to set a `Const` to the BackColor value displayed in the properties window, which is something like `&H80000005&` - just out of curiosity, is there anyway this could be used in place of the `Long` value somehow?

Comment: No expert in this but I think &H80000005 is an index into the system palette - if you want more flexibility then an RGB-derived Long might be more useful.  EDIT: here you go - https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/139131-userform-color-to-rgb-values

Comment: @TimWilliams you're an absolute darling! Works perfectly, so I take it the error was two-fold. First I used a variable in which the assigned values were removed and secondly I used RGB instead of  windows colour. Is that right?

Comment: Using RGB is fine but setting the variables in the workbook open routine makes your code a little vulnerable to errors which end up resetting your variables.